# whats is happening with my code

Tags: php

I want to check if notificatins are > 0 then there are notification else then 
there are no notifications available, but however if I change status to 1 my rows goes to my second if -  else seen, but I want to check how many notifications are seen or unread , but if I change status count like all

```
public function websocket(){
        $data = $this->session->userdata('log');
        $user_id = $data['id'];
        $timestamp = 1493618633;
        // $entryData = array(
     //        'category' => $_POST['category'], 
     //        'title'    => $_POST['title'], 
     //        'article'  => $_POST['article'], 
     //        'when'     => time()
  //       );
        $array = $this->notification->getNotifications($timestamp, $user_id);
        if ($array > 0) {
            if (empty(array_filter(array_column($array, 'status')))) { 
                echo 'unread'; 
            }else{
                echo 'seen'; 
            }
        }else{
            $this->json(array('msg' => 'there are no notifications available'));
        }
        $context = new ZMQContext();
        $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
        $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");
        $socket->send(json_encode('hola'));
    }
```

Comment: to start with, does `($array > 0)` need to be `(count($array) > 0)`?

Comment: Try to check the array size  if ($array.size() > 0)

Comment: anyway goes to seen

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you're only checking if `$array` exists (which it does because it's initialized in the line directly above). If using `count($array) > 0` or `$array.size() > 0` is still returning the undesired result, try throwing a quick and dirty `print_r($array)` right after the initialization of the variable to check and make sure that your notification system isn't returning an empty or malformed array.